# 3d.js - how to wrap the text around a circle as simply

Tags: svg, d3.js

I would like to make a circle(image attached) and use the background image as my graphics. but the text around the circle should be dynamic. so how can i wrap the text around a text with simply approach.

this is what i am looking for:

[image: Project name goes like this]

any one help me?

code :

```
var title = "Project names maximum" 
var diameter = 150;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", diameter + 50)
      .attr("height", diameter + 50)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(25,25)");

    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")")
      .attr("r", diameter / 2);

     svg.selectAll('text') //how to proceed here?
      .data(requiredDegrees)
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .text(title);
```

[Here is my Try - jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00eowuhe/1/)

Comment: Try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/wcWUE/

Comment: I tried, but i am not able to set the `text` other then hello1

Comment: it is because he uses a dataset, you must change the label with your string